# my filters shifts the rows up and deletes the first row

Tags: excel, vba, filter, delete-row, autofilter

I have a sub that is supposed to do several things: first, it deletes all rows in which the cell of the first column is empty. then, it deletes all rows in which the cells of the first column are duplicates. finally it deletes all rows of which the cells of the fifth column have a certain value.

it works very well, however, it shifts all of the rows up when it is done running through (i set it to start at the second row) and then deletes that row (even if none of my filters apply).

This is the code:

```
sub filter
    Dim ws As Worksheet

  'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook.
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("result")
  ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message appears
  
  'Clear any existing filters
  On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0

  '1. Apply Filter
  ws.range("A2:I10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
  
  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.range("A2:I10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  
  

   ws.range("A2:I10000").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes

  ws.range("A2:I10000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("BE", "BG", "DK", "DE", "EE", "FI", "FR", "GR", "IE", "IT", "HR", "LV", "LT", "LU", "MT", "NL", "AT", "PL", "PT", "RO", "SE", "SK", "SI", "ES", "CZ", "HU", "CY")

  '2. Delete Rows
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.range("A2:I10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

end sub
```

it is supposed to leave the first rows, since these are headers for all of the values below.

Thank you in advanve

Answer (score 0):

### AutoFilter/RemoveDuplicates Sandwich

**Highlights**

- You apply `AutoFilter` to the complete range (table) including the headers.
- You delete rows from the data range i.e. the range (table) without the headers, or you'll delete the headers.
- When deleting rows from a range, the reference (its address) changes ('shrinks') which is illustrated with the `Debug.Print` lines in the code.
- `RemoveDuplicates` doesn't change the range reference. Therefore the ranges are newly set before the final filtering.
- When all data rows are deleted, using the data range (`drg`) e.g. to get its address (`drg.Address`), will fail with an `Object required` error (`424`) because it has 'run out of scope' i.e. it would have no rows. Note that it will not be `Nothing`.
- Note the importance of the two occurrences of `ws.AutoFilterMode = False`. If you don't use them, you'll be asked to delete the **entire** rows and if you reject, an error will occur.

[image]

```vb
Sub FilterData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Result")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False

    ' Allow user to view the worksheet if a warning message appears.
    If Not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
    ' An error would occur if 'ThisWorkbook' were not active!
    If Not ws Is ActiveSheet Then ws.Activate
  
    Dim hrrg As Range: Set hrrg = ws.Range("A2:I2") ' Header Row Range
    
    Dim trg As Range ' Table Range (has headers)
    Dim drg As Range ' Data Range (no headers)
    Dim frg As Range ' Filtered Data Range (no headers)
    
    ' 1.) Filter
    Set trg = SetColumns(hrrg)
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty range
    If trg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers
    Set drg = trg.Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
Debug.Print "0.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & drg.Address(0, 0)
    
    trg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
    On Error Resume Next
        Set frg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    If Not frg Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print "1.)", "frg: " & frg.Address(0, 0)
        frg.Delete xlShiftUp
        Set frg = Nothing
    End If
If trg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Debug.Print "1.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & drg.Address(0, 0)
Else
    Debug.Print "1.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & "No object"
End If
    
    ' 2.) Remove Duplicates
    If trg.Rows.Count >= 3 Then
        trg.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes
        ' There are at least two rows.
        Set trg = SetColumns(hrrg)
        Set drg = trg.Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    'Else ' too few rows (headers + 2 rows needed); no duplicates; do nothing
    End If
If trg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Debug.Print "2.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & drg.Address(0, 0)
Else
    Debug.Print "2.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & "No object"
End If
    
    ' 3.) Filter
    If trg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' only headers
    trg.AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "BE", "BG", "DK", "DE", "EE", "FI", "FR", "GR", "IE", _
        "IT", "HR", "LV", "LT", "LU", "MT", "NL", "AT", "PL", _
        "PT", "RO", "SE", "SK", "SI", "ES", "CZ", "HU", "CY")
    On Error Resume Next
        Set frg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    If Not frg Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print "3.)", "frg: " & frg.Address(0, 0)
        frg.Delete xlShiftUp
        Set frg = Nothing
    End If
If trg.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Debug.Print "3.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & drg.Address(0, 0)
Else
    Debug.Print "3.)", "trg: " & trg.Address(0, 0), "drg: " & "No object"
End If
    
End Sub

Function SetColumns( _
    ByVal FirstRowRange As Range) _
As Range
    
    With FirstRowRange.Rows(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function ' empty range
        Set SetColumns = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

**Results in the Immediate Window**

```
0.)           trg: A2:I22   drg: A3:I22
1.)           frg: A6:I7,A9:I9,A11:I11,A22:I22
1.)           trg: A2:I17   drg: A3:I17
2.)           trg: A2:I13   drg: A3:I13
3.)           frg: A4:I4,A6:I6,A10:I10,A12:I13
3.)           trg: A2:I8    drg: A3:I8
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This answered my question and also fixed some of the other issues I was having with the code!